# get days before password expires in Solaris

Tags: users, solaris, password

I wish to know the number of days "remaining" before my account password expires in Solaris.

I'm using `chage` command in linux to get this information.

`passwd -S <userid>` works to get the the number of days left for the password of  to expire on both Linux and Solaris but unfortunately this `passwd` requires `sudo` elevated privileges.

**Note:** I need to know the days remaining for the password to expire on my own account that i login with and not of any other users

I will eventually use the solution here into ansible tool.

Comment: In the /etc/shadow file there are 9 fields which can be modiified by chage. See "man shadow" and "man chage".

Comment: @CinaedSimson `chage` is a Linux command.  This is a Solaris question.

Answer (score 1):

There's apparently no way to get this information on Solaris if your login is file-based (`/etc/passwd`/`/etc/shadow`) and you don't have privileges to read `/etc/shadow`.  (And note that reading `/etc/shadow` gives you access to the hashed passwords in `/etc/shadow`. You then have the ability to perform brute-force attacks to crack them...)

If you do have root access, you can use

```
logins -x -l username
```

The result will look something like this:

```
-bash-4.4# logins -x -l ahenle
ahenle          1024    users           100     
                        /home/ahenle
                        /usr/bin/bash
                        PS 101720 -1 -1 -1
```

If you don't have root access (or similar privileges to read `/etc/shadow`), that last line will be

```
                        LK 010170 0 0 0
```

That os zeros for the numeric values (`010170` is zero days after 1 Jan 1970).

From [the `logins` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E72487/logins-8.html):

> **logins(8)**
>
> **Name**
>
> logins - list user and system login information
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/logins [-S repository] [
> -admoprstux] [-g group...]
>      [-l login_name...]
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> This command displays information on user, role, and system logins
> known to the system. Contents of the output is controlled by the
> command options and can include the following: user, role, or system
> login; user id number; `passwd` account field value (user name or
> other information); primary group name; primary group id; multiple
> group names; multiple group ids; home directory; login shell; **and
> four password-aging parameters**. ...
>
> ...
>
> **Options**
>
> Options may be used together. If so, any login that matches any
> criteria are displayed.
>
> The following options are supported:
>
> ...
>
> –l login_name...
>
> Selects the requested login.
>
> ...
>
> –x
>
> Prints an extended set of information about each selected user. The extended information includes home directory, login shell, and
> password-aging information, each displayed on a separate line. The
> password information currently consists of password status:
>
> NP  Account has no password
>
> LK  Account is locked for UNIX authentication
>
> AL  Account is automatically locked due to exceeding the number of
> configured authentication failures.
>
> NL  Account is a no login account
>
> UP  This account has not yet been activated by the administrator and
> cannot be used.
>
> PS  Account probably has a valid password
>
> UN  Account password status is unknown. That is, it is not a
> recognizable hashed password or any of the above entries. See
> crypt(3C) for valid password hashes.
>
> **If the login is passworded, status is followed by the date the password was last changed, the number of days required between
> changes**, and the number of days allowed before a change is required.
> The password-aging information shows the time interval that the user
> receives a password expiration warning message (when logging on)
> before the password expires.